# ArrayList.add() method causing NullPointerException

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

The class LongInteger is causing the following error when run:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at LongInteger.breakString(LongInteger.java:38)
at LongInteger.<init>(LongInteger.java:17)
at LongInteger.main(LongInteger.java:149)
```

Here are some relevant class excerpts:

```
public class LongInteger extends Object {
private ArrayList<String> storedStrings;          


  // Constructor
 public LongInteger(String s) {
    this.setInputString(s);
    this.breakString(this.inputString);       //Exception @ line 17
}

 /**
  * the purpose of this method is to break the input string into an 
  * ArrayList<String> where each String has a length of 9 or less.
  */
 private void breakString(String s){         
    if(s.length()>9){
        storedStrings.add(0,s.substring(s.length()-9,s.length()));
        this.breakString(s.substring(0,s.length()-9));
    } else {
        this.storedStrings.add(0,s);        //Exception @ line 38
    }
 }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    LongInteger a = new LongInteger("12345");   //Exception @ line 149
    }
}
```

I am at a loss as to what is causing this NullPointerException. Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Is "storedStrings" ever initialized?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You never instantiate `storedStrings`.  Try changing:

```
private ArrayList<String> storedStrings;
```

To:

```
private ArrayList<String> storedStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
```

When you have the line:

```
this.storedStrings.add(0,s);
```

It is invoking the method `add` on an *instance* of `ArrayList<String>` stored in `this.storedStrings`.  The `new` operator is how you get new instances of things.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create your storedStrings variable before using it.

```
ArrayList<String> storedStrings = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: `storedStrings` was created, it just wasn't initialized.